# Spring transactional annotation rollback test doesn't seem to go well

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions

This is the Controller code:

```java
@GetMapping("/test/hello")
    public String test()  {
        Member m = memberService.transactionTest();
        return "haha";
    }
```

and this is Service code:

```
   @Transactional(rollbackFor = NullPointerException.class)
    public Member transactionTest() {
            Member m = Member.builder()
                    .username("rollback")
                    .age(32)
                    .team(teamRepository.findById(1L).get())
                    .coach(coachRepository.findById(1L).get())
                    .build();
            memberRepository.save(m);
            exception();
            return m;
    }

    public void exception(){
        Member m = null;
        m.getUsername();
    }
```

As far as I know when it finishes it should rollback
because RuntimeException occurs but insert process works so well so I want to know why.

Comment: Is the repository transactional as well? And if so, does it have default propagation? Btw, the default behavior would be to roll back on any RuntimeException, so there's no need to mention `rollbackFor` explicitly (I'm not sure whether this will add to the default behavior or override it).

Comment: Which database are you using, by anychange MySQL?

Comment: M.Deinum It's conneced to MariaDB sur
Thomas i didn't set any propagatopn setting and I put Transactional option on that method only T.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Optional.get()` throws `NoSuchElementException` (and not null pointer).

[From javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html):

> `public T get()`

> If a value is present in this `Optional`, returns the value, otherwise throws `NoSuchElementException`....

By `rollbackFor = NullPointerException.class` you exclude `NoSuchElementException` from rollback-able exceptions.